# Problema no retorno da resposta via $http.post()

Tags: angularjs, http, request

Estou tentando pegar apenas um valor do retorno `HTTP` mas não estou conseguindo.

```
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.sendPost = function() {
    var dataObj = {
            name : $scope.newName
    };  
    var res = $http.post('xxxx.consulta.php', dataObj)

    res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.hello = data;
    });  
 }
})
```

Quando executo a página no navegador ela me retorna o objeto `JSON`:

```
[{"id":"13","nome":"Yuri","departamento":"EAD","img":"https:\/\/image.freepik.com\/icones-gratis\/perfil-macho-utilizador-sombra_318-40244.png"}]
```

Gostaria de salvar apenas o id e nome, como faço? Já tentei
`data.id` ou na `view` `{{hello.id}}` e não funcionou...

Comment: Tente isso: `$scope.hello = data.data`

Comment: Não funcionou...

Comment: use `console.log(data)` dentro do success, o que ele mostra no seu console?

Comment: [Object]
0: Object
departamento: "EAD"
id: "13"
img: "https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratis/perfil-macho-utilizador-sombra_318-40244.png"
nome: "Yuri"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: E se você fizer assim: `= data[0]` ?

Comment: Deu certo assim, mas acredito que não seja assim...pq vai ter varios array em uma consulta, dessa forma vou pegar apenas um...

Comment: para isso voce precisaria fazer um loop na array, vou adiciinar resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema, conforme dito nos comentários, ocorre pois você está retornando uma array, mas deseja utilizar apenas um objeto (pelo que entendi). Para isso você precisa fazer um filtro, ou loop. Veja esses exemplos:

```
angular.forEach(data, function(obj){
    if(sua logica aqui) {
        return obj; //retorne ou aplique o valor ao seu objeto.
    }
})
```

Assim você está interagindo por toda a array, passando em cada item e fazendo uma verificação.

Ou então você pode fazer um filtro, veja:

```
$scope.valor = $filter('filter')(data,{id: $scope.seuvalor});
```

Os dois métodos irão filtrar sua array e atribuir apenas um valor da array. Para utilizar estes métodos, vamos supor que você queira pegar o objeto que tenha o mesmo nome do seu `$scope.newName`, então você faria assim:

```
angular.forEach(data, function(obj){
    if(obj.name == $scope.newName) {
        return obj; //retorne ou aplique o valor ao seu objeto.
        //ou
        $scope.novoValor = obj; //Atribui todo o objeto ao $scope 
    }
})

//Ou então

$scope.novoValor = $filter('filter')(data,{name: $scope.newName});
```

Answer (score 2):

O conceito é bem simples, isso é um objeto JSON, logo, você tem que jogar isso numa variável e usá-lo como no exemplo abaixo, pode tanto fazer consulta por posição, como num laço, pelo seu controller, dá pra jogar no `$scope.collection = data`:

**"collection"** seria o mesmo que uma variável do tipo data, como abaixo:

```
var data = [
  {"id":"13","nome":"Yuri","departamento":"EAD","img":"https:\/\/image.freepik.com\/icones-gratis\/perfil-macho-utilizador-sombra_318-40244.png"},

  {"id":"14","nome":"Yuri","departamento":"EAD","img":"https:\/\/image.freepik.com\/icones-gratis\/perfil-macho-utilizador-sombra_318-40244.png"}
]

//exemplo 1
console.log(data[0].id)
console.log(data[0].nome)

//exemplo 2
console.log(data[1].id)
console.log(data[1].nome)

//no laço:
for (var i in data) {
  console.log(data[i].nome)
  console.log(data[i].id)
}
```

Na view, você pode usar o ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="dado in collection">
   {{ dado.id }} <br>
   {{ dado.nome }}
</div>
```

Ou pegar pela posição na view:

```
<div>
       {{ collection[0].id }} <br>
       {{ collection[0].nome }}<hr>

       {{ collection[1].id }} <br>
       {{ collection[1].nome }}
</div>
```